# File hierarchy vs Package hierarchy in IDE(Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, package, hierarchy

Let assume I have such class:

package **com.*stackoverflow*.hierarchy**;

class A {}

that is located in ~/MyProject/src/**com/hierarchy**

Is that possible to avoid compilation errors in IDE for A-class (like 
*The declared package "**com.*stackoverflow*.hierarchy**" does not match the expected package "**com.hierarchy**"*)

I've tried to search some answer in Java Build Path properties Project Properties. But I failed. Maybe some body can help with this staff?

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want to do this?

Comment: @Gray Well... I have dynamically developed project that was ported from .NET to Java. So some things are go wrong with Java best practices. Project is compiled fine with Ant. But I would like to run my tests through Eclipse so I need it be compiled in Eclipse too.

Comment: Any reason to not have Eclipse correct the packages for you?  Is there a problem with putting them into the right directory hierarchy?

Comment: @Gray >Any reason to not have Eclipse correct the packages for you?< Sorry don't understand here. >Is there a problem with putting them into the right directory hierarchy< Yes! If I'll put them in the right directory I'll get inconsistency with SVN.

Comment: Eclipse can correct the packages of the files in question if you let it and if you have subclipse installed, they will be moved in SVN as well.

Comment: @Gray The point is - I don't need(that is forbidden) to move that packages on SVN!

Comment: `svn move` is forbidden?  Huh, ok. That's unfortunate.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

It is the Java problem but not the eclipse problem.

[From  7.2.1 Storing Packages in a File System  in The Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.2.1):

> Under this simple organization of packages, an implementation of the
>   Java platform would transform a package name into a pathname by
>   concatenating the components of the package name, placing a file name
>   separator (directory indicator) between adjacent components.
>
> For example, if this simple organization were used on a UNIX system,
>   where the file name separator is /, the package name:
>
> ```
> jag.scrabble.board
> ```
>
> would be transformed into the directory name:
>
> ```
> jag/scrabble/board
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> com.sun.sunsoft.DOE
> ```
>
> would be transformed to the directory name:
>
> ```
> com/sun/sunsoft/DOE
> ```

Your packages name should match the file pathname .So you should change `Class A` 's package from `package com.stackoverflow.hierarchy` to `package com.hierarchy`

or  put the `Class A`  into the folder `/MyProject/src/com/stackoverflow/hierarchy`

Comment: Yes that is obvious. My answer is about different thing. I ask about outwitting of Eclipse IDE